# Accepting map parameters

Tags: go

I have a simple function which tests whether a string is an integer

```
func testInt(str string, m map[bool]) int {
    _,e := strconv.ParseInt(str, 0, 64);
    return m[nil == e] * 7;
}
```

where the map being passed contains `m[true] = 1`, `m[false] = 0`. However, when I attempt to run this Go complains

```
1: syntax error: unexpected )
```

Either I cannot pass maps around as parameters in this way, or else I am doing this entirely wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `map` maps keys to values, using the syntax

```
map[KeyType]ValueType
```

(see https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

In your function, you have not specified a `ValueType`, causing this syntax error. It looks like you want a `map[bool]int`.

Comment: Yes, that works.  Given the philosophy of Go that is logical - in hindsight :-)